# C# EntityFramework Up method ¿ What about if sql fails in the middle?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, atomic

I am using entity framework.
This is my up method:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("Users", "atribute21", c => c.String(unicode: false));

        Sql("wrong sql command");
    }
```

I intencionally write a bad sql command, the point is the sql code that will be executed will be:

```
 alter table `Users` add column `atribute21` longtext 
 wrong sql command
```

So The entity framework will  execute the first sql sentence and change in my database the attribute "atribute21", but after that it will fail and the table __migrationhistory will not be modified.

So, actually Entity framework becomes in a inconsistent state. Some changes have been applied to the database with the update command but the migration is not complete. In fact I can even not rollback with the  update-database TargetMigration:"migration", or update-database or anything.

The only way to solve this is manually deleting the "atribute21" from the users table, deleting the wrong sql code and migrating again. This solution in this example is pretty simple but it is not scalable, for example, what about if i have 30 sql commands in the up method to fill the data in the database, and one of them fails.

¿How I can recover from this using entity framework?

¿Does not should the up method be a sql transaction by default in entity framework?

¿How can I configure entity framework to achieve that the up method will be a sql transaction?

Note:
I figure out that adding sql begin and sql end to the up method is a way, but I think this is not a good solution, I would like something automatic.

**EDITED:**

The automatic rollback in the up method exist when you use Microsoft Sql Server, but I am using MySQL/MariaDb and does not occur.

Comment: I think that a rollback occurs...

Comment: @IgorQuirino I tried it and the rollback does not occur, the database is modified even with the update-database command fails.

Comment: Also keep in mind you should have Down() code to reverse the migration.

Comment: @SteveGreene I can not use that code when the transaction fail at middle, because the recovery  code will fail too.

Comment: @IgorQuirino I tried again and the rollback occurs when I am using a sql server, but I am using MariaDB. Maybe I should configure something that I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

**"How I can recover from this using entity framework?"**

**"How can I configure entity framework to achieve that the up method will be a sql transaction?"**

Try using **TransactionScope**

```
using System.Transactions;
```

**Code:**

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        //Do whatever

        transaction.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**"Does not should the up method be a sql transaction by default in entity framework?"**

- @IgorQuirino I tried it and the rollback does not occur, the database is modified even with the update-database command fails.
- So, no...

Happy to help you!